# ggtext creates excessive white space between subtitle and title

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, ggtext

I have created a plot in `ggplot` and am using `ggtext` to colorize particular words in my subtitle. While *that works*, every time that I render the plot, there is an excessive amount of white space at the top. The code that is helping with rendering the text is below, and this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd9px.png). Any thoughts on what I should do?

````
  filter(threatened == 1,
         !is.na(year_last_seen)) %>%
  count(year_last_seen, threat_type) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year_last_seen, values_from = n) %>%
  mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  nest(c('1900-1919', '1920-1939', '1940-1959', '1960-1979', '1980-1999', '2000-2020')) %>%
  mutate('2020_sum' = map_dbl(data, sum)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(threat_type = fct_reorder(threat_type, `2020_sum`)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_dumbbell(aes(y = threat_type, x = `Before 1900`, xend = `2020_sum`), 
                color='#E7E3D9', size = 1.5,
                colour_x = '#1E5871', colour_xend = '#8F0700', 
                size_x = 4, size_xend = 4) + 
# This is the text that is helping me colorize particular words in the subtitle.  
labs(title = "Number of Plants Threated",
       subtitle = "Change from <b style='color:#1E5871'>< 1900</b> through <b style='color:#8F0700'>2020</b>",
       x = '',
       y = '') +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_markdown())```
````

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Remove all styling details that don't matter for the problem, and provide some data (possibly made up) so the code runs.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem using the `mtcars` dataset and your `labs()` and `theme()` function calls. As Claus mentions, it would be useful to have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I've had similar issues when manually inserting linebreaks in the subtitle text using `<br>`. I've found that removing these and instead adjusting the size of the textbox using `theme(plot.subtitle = element_textbox(width = unit()))` sorts things out.